# Python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Let a dictionary called ps be defined as

```
ps = {1:(1,1),2:(3,2),3:(3,-3),4:(-3,4),5:(-2,-2),6:(3,3),7:(1,-1)}
```

where the values are points on a graph.

Write a function `first_quad` that returns a dictionary whose keys are 2-tuples (points) that are in the first quadrant (points whose x and y coordinates are not negative), whose associated values are their distance from the origin: 
for the ps dictionary above the result is

```
{(3,2):3.605551275463989,(1,1):1.4142135623730951, (3,3):4.242640687119285}
```

I just can't seem to get how to proceed with the problem. All suggestions will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You really need to make a stab at this yourself. Break it down into parts, trying to solve the whole thing at once is what makes it feel overwhelming. 1. Get the values. 2. Filter them to those where both x and y are positive. 3. Compute the distance from origin 4. Add point and distance to dict. If one of those steps doesn't work, ask a question about that specific problem and provide a [MCVE]. As is, this question is too broad.

Comment: I knew how to take out the distance, get the values. couldn't figure out how to put it together. I apologise for not providing more specification to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This conditional dictionary comprehension should do exactly what you want:

```
>>> import math
>>> {v: math.hypot(v[0], v[1]) for v in ps.values() if v[0] >= 0 and v[1] >= 0}
{(1, 1): 1.4142135623730951, (3, 2): 3.605551275463989, (3, 3): 4.242640687119285}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think that I could just put the distance calculating statement in the value part.

Comment: @DilsherBhat You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer. For the next question, however, please provide some code that shows your attempts. It makes it easier to judge which parts need explaining or on what basis to put an answer. A conditional dictionary comprehension might be to advanced or just the right tool. :)

Comment: Accept the answer ? And yes, I will make sure to show my work up to the point I do in the future.

Comment: @DilsherBhat There should be a "checkmark" left of the post that you can click. See also [this screenshot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/317868)